# Handle Events in Custom Control Code Behind

Tags: wpf, events, automation, custom-controls, code-behind

Ok, that probably is a pretty dumb question but I have searched quite a while but could not find a solution for this that works...

I have a Custom control inherited from `Control`, which shall include code behind automation.

For examble select all text of a controls `TextBox` when selected, or generate a list of close matches when the content of that `TextBox` is changed.

```
public class vokDataGridEdit : Control
{
    static vokDataGridEdit()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(vokDataGridEdit), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(vokDataGridEdit)));

        // Events internal to control (??? found on some how-to's)
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(vokDataGridEdit), UIElement.GotKeyboardFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnSelectContent), true);
    }

    // Dependecy Properties ...

    // The Event that shall Fire when the TextBox gets Focus / Editing Mode
    public static void SelectContent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox tb)
        {
            tb.SelectAll();
        }
    }
}
```

And the controls Style Template:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns       = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x     = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:ccont = "clr-namespace:App.Controls">

    <!-- Default style for the Validation Buttons -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ccont:vokDataGridEdit}">

        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"  Value="true" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>

                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ccont:vokDataGridEdit}">

                    <TextBox Text                               = "{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ccont:vokDataGridEdit}}"
                             BorderThickness                    = "0"
                             ContextMenuService.Placement       = "Right"
                             ContextMenuService.PlacementTarget = "{Binding Path=., RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                             GotKeyboardFocus                   = "SelectContent">

                        <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate>

                                        <Border CornerRadius    = "5"
                                                Background      = "LightGray"
                                                BorderThickness = "1" 
                                                BorderBrush     = "Gray"
                                                Padding         = "2">

                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                                                <!-- Title -->
                                                <TextBlock Text="Test" />

                                                <!-- TODO: List of matches -->
                                                <TextBox Text               = "{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ccont:vokDataGridEdit}}" 
                                                         BorderThickness    = "0" />

                                            </StackPanel>

                                        </Border>

                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </ContextMenu.Template>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </TextBox.ContextMenu>

                    </TextBox>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Question 1:** How can I bind the event `SelectContent` (to select all `TextBox` content when it get focus, nb: it is part of a `DataGrid` for the `CellEditingTemplate`) to `GotKeyboardFocus`? Events are normaly fine in the Apps code, but for the Custom Control they do not work as there is no "Code Behind" really for the Style...

**Question 2:** Assuming I have a dependency Property containing an array of words. Based on the content of the `TextBox`, I would like to select a few words from the Array in the Dependency Property and pass them to a `ListBox` in the Custom Control (the Content of the `ListBox` shall only be managed by the Custom Control, not by anyone using that control. Is there a prefered/canonical MVVM schema on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Partial Solution:**

Finaly I got event on the direct controls to work (controls in a `ContextMenu` still don't get EventHandlers...).

Apparently the point was using `GetTemplateChild()` in order to get the TextBox by name, and then associate the Event handlers:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns       = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x     = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:ccont = "clr-namespace:App.Controls">

    <!-- Default style for the Validation Buttons -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ccont:vokDataGridEdit}">

        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"  Value="true" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>

                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ccont:vokDataGridEdit}">

                    <TextBox Text                               = "{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ccont:vokDataGridEdit}}"
                             BorderThickness                    = "0"
                             ContextMenuService.Placement       = "Right"
                             ContextMenuService.PlacementTarget = "{Binding Path=., RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                             x:Name                             = "TextBox">

                        <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu x:Name="Menu">
                                <ContextMenu.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate>

                                        <Border CornerRadius    = "5"
                                                Background      = "LightGray"
                                                BorderThickness = "1" 
                                                BorderBrush     = "Gray"
                                                Padding         = "2">

                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                                                <!-- Title -->
                                                <TextBlock Text="Test" x:Name = "Test" />

                                                <!-- TODO: List of matches -->
                                                <TextBox Text               = "{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ccont:vokDataGridEdit}}" 
                                                         BorderThickness    = "0" />

                                            </StackPanel>

                                        </Border>

                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </ContextMenu.Template>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </TextBox.ContextMenu>

                    </TextBox>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And Code (Dependency Properties not shown):

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace App.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// DataGrid Edit control (see: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/wpf-routed-events/ for RoutedEvents)
    /// </summary>
    public class vokDataGridEdit : Control
    {
        static vokDataGridEdit()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(vokDataGridEdit), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(vokDataGridEdit)));
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            // Demo purpose only, check for previous instances and remove the handler first  
            if (this.GetTemplateChild("TextBox") is TextBox button)
            {
                button.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown   += this.SelectContentPreparation;
                button.GotKeyboardFocus             += this.SelectContent;
                button.MouseDoubleClick             += this.SelectContent;
                //button.GotFocus                     += this.SelectContent;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Prepare the Control to ensure it has focus before subsequent event fire
        /// </summary>
        private void SelectContentPreparation(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is TextBox tb)
            {
                if (!tb.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                    tb.Focus();
                }
            }
        }

        private void SelectContent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is TextBox tb)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                tb.SelectAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you should post only one question, not multiple. Regarding first one you can use `EventSetter` e.g. in implicit `Style` in `UserControl`'s resources:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <EventSetter Event="GotKeyboardFocus" Handler="SelectContent"/>
</Style>
```

Regarding second question - implement a property, which is subset of your list and do update it accordingly e.g. if dependency property was changed(see property changed callback) or some another values were changed which the subset depends on.

Alternatively you could use a behavior for the `TextBox` and handle events you need there. See e.g. select all behavior:

```
public class SelectAllBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    private bool _doSelectAll = false;
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.GotFocus += AssociatedObject_GotFocus;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseUp += AssociatedObject_MouseUp;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseDown += AssociatedObject_MouseDown;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_doSelectAll)
        {
            AssociatedObject.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (()=>{ AssociatedObject.SelectAll(); }));
        }
        _doSelectAll = false;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _doSelectAll = !AssociatedObject.IsFocused;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_GotFocus(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectAll();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.GotFocus -= AssociatedObject_GotFocus;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseUp -= AssociatedObject_MouseUp;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseDown -= AssociatedObject_MouseDown;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }
}
```

Using this behavior in XAML:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
<TextBox Text="Some text">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:SelectAllBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Hi Rekshino, I added the Style to the TextBox but build fails claiming it need `x:Class` directive, and anyway the handler will be marked not found in the designer... See question for code.

Comment: See my answer, put it to the __`UserControl`'s resources__. The handler must be also in `UserControl`.

Comment: Pardon me if I don't really understand. But the Control is a Custom Control with a Style in `Generic.xaml` not a `UserControl` with code behind. Hence I don't have a `UserControl` xaml file... Do I miss something?

Comment: I have extended my answer. Have you worked with behaviors?

Comment: No, I did not use any behaviours and to be honnest I have no experience using them nore where to start for this particular case. :(

Comment: OK I found a way to finaly add the EventHandlers (see my answer below). However, because this is a `TextBox` which is generated when editing a `DataGrid`, the `SelectAll` on focus does not work initially. Still looking for a solution but if anyone has a clue I'd welcome that!

Comment: I adde an example of behavior, wich selects all the text in the `TextBox` on `GotFocus`.

Comment: Thanks for that example, look clear. In general is there a situation where you would prefer Behaviour vs Events? Or put another way: is there a criteria which would tend to Behaviour even if there is more code behind to write?

Comment: I wouldn't say behavior vs events, but behavior vs code behind. I see behavior not as code behind, because of it is a separate and independent functionality, wich can declarative be used in XAML. I try never use a code behind, but only the behaviors. So for me there is no rule of thumb.